# php move_uploaded_file forcely gives new name

Tags: php

I am trying to upload file using php, code snippt

```
$upload_path = "/var/upload/" . $_FILES['mfile']['name'];
if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['mfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_path))
    echo "file uploaded";
else
    echo "upload failed";
```

Note: that /var/upload directory exists and has 777 permission.

The code prints "upload failed"

When I check /var/upload directory, there is file f_505bf77bd8a0f_mypdf.pdf. What went wrong?

Added log ( as per requested by loler):

```
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: showdebug in /Volumes/data/htdocs/ebeu/upload.php on line 558, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: showdebug in /Volumes/data/htdocs/ebeu/upload.php on line 559, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: accessories in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 21, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: pmaterial in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 27, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: occupation_bwc in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 33, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: occupation_bwc in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 75, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: occupation_spec in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 75, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined index: babycarrier in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 78, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: accessories_all in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 79, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
[Fri Sep 21 10:58:31 2012] [error] [client ::1] PHP Notice:  Undefined variable: pmaterials_all in /var/www/my/web/folder/myupload.php on line 80, referer: http://localhost/upload/test/upload.php
```

**Added var_dump($_FILES)**

```
array(1) {
  ["mfile"]=&gt;
  array(5) {
    ["name"]=&gt;
    string(23) "mypdf.pdf"
    ["type"]=&gt;
    string(15) "application/pdf"
    ["tmp_name"]=&gt;
    string(26) "/var/tmp/phpUl6k50"
    ["error"]=&gt;
    int(0)
    ["size"]=&gt;
    int(478704)
  }
}
```

Comment: What's your [`upload_tmp_dir`](http://us.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.upload-tmp-dir)? Are you sure this file you're seeing is related to your upload, and not from somewhere else? (If you trust user provided filenames that much, you will overwrite existing files eventually.)

Comment: can you check Apache error log?

Comment: DCoder, I am 110% ;-) sure on this. Coz I remove all files from directory and tried script. I even verified file opening directory.

Comment: loler, I added log in above question

Comment: I would var_dump $_FILES because I would bet the $_FILES['mfile'] may not be what you are posting. "mfile" maybe wrong

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar, you just said that it returns "upload failed", but can you go to Apache error log to see more detailed error message?

Comment: `move_uploaded_file()` throws a warning on failure which you should be seeing somewhere. Try enabling detailed error reporting, eg at the top of your script `ini_set('display_errors', 'On'); error_reporting(E_ALL);`

Comment: now please do what @adrianj98 said. Coz errors say you have not defined variables correctly.

Comment: adrianj98, 200% sure it is 'mfile :-).

Comment: does rename($_FILES['mfile']['tmp_name'], $upload_path) work? I think it is not an apache problem. since the file is already there that means apache  did its work already.

Comment: how is removing help, I want to save file in same name in sever as it is in local pc.

Comment: Phil, move_uploaded_file is returning false. There is no error of any level. As per PHP Doc, move_uploaded_file return true or false if there is no syntactical error.

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar try `$upload_path = "/var/upload/" . trim($_FILES['mfile']['name']);`

Comment: @KrishnaSunuwar I would try testing the `$_FILES['mfile']['tmp_name']` with [`is_uploaded_file()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.is-uploaded-file.php) before attempting to move it in that case

Answer (score 1):

Try this code for upload your files..

```
if (file_exists("/var/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]))
  {
  echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
  }
else
  {
  move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],
  "/var/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
  echo "Stored in: " . "/var/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
  }
```

Comment: for sure, there is no file with that name

Answer (score 0):

In your `var_dump()` there `$_FILES["file"]["name"]` length is 23, but it should be 9. so try to `trim` this string. instead of

```
$upload_path = "/var/upload/" . $_FILES['mfile']['name'];
```

try to write

```
$upload_path = "/var/upload/" . trim($_FILES['mfile']['name']);
```